# Is there a fun guide on infant cognitive abilities?

Tags: infant, newborn, cognitive-development, media

I have a simple question: Is there any simple guide, site, book where all the progression of the newborn's cognitive development is described? Preferably, it should be of the format

> day 10: most infants begin to recognize day and night etc.

I am not interested in any deep, all theory encompassing book. Just a fun guide on when I can say "wow my baby now must have this ability!"

Comment: Just from my point of view, that's great but sometimes it won't work as expected. He/she might be late on certain aspects but not to worry children are indeed different. My insurance sent me a book "Taking care of your child" best I have read since I had my boy so far. It has everything in details even what to give incase of what. Goodluck.

Answer (score 2):

Try The Wonder Weeks. That gives details of when babies supposedly make mental leaps that allow them to understand new things about the world and develop new skills.

For a more general guide, the Baby Centre website also has a milestone chart which gives an idea of when babies will be able to do certain things. It goes all the way up to about 3 years so not just for babies.

http://www.babycentre.co.uk/a6476/milestone-chart-one-to-six-months

They also have more detail on what to expect by week e.g.

http://www.babycentre.co.uk/s1001638/1-week-old

I don't know of anything that quite goes down to the detail of what happens on any particular day of the baby's life but even if there was, I don't think it would be very accurate. Even with a monthly guide, you will find a lot of variation between different babies. You should use any of these sources as a rough guide and not  read too much into it if the baby does things a bit earlier or later. But it can be fun to check the chart and think "in a month, my baby might be able to... ".